# Does "'Collapsing Parallel Worlds" remove Locations that are in play?

Tags: dc-comics-deck-building

The crisis 'Collapsing Parallel World's forces one of the players to exchange their deck and discard pile for a new 10 card deck.  Do they lose the Locations they have in play?

Answer (score 2):

The Crisis only affects cards in your deck or discard pile. Cards left in play (such as locations), and cards in your hand, are neither, so they are not affected.

This is corroborated by [this Board Game Geek thread](https://boardgamegeek.com/article/16702474#16702474):

> This was asked earlier on here and I believe Matt [Hyra, creator of the game] answered it with yes they keep their hand and locations just the discard and deck piles go.

Unfortunately, I have been unable to find the original reference.